# Switching to mui5 sx prop from makeStyles- typescript error (no overload matches this call) passing object with position

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a component that I'm trying to convert to mui 5. This is how it was:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
   imageContainer: {
     display: "flex",
     width: "65%",
     float: "left",
     marginRight: "2px",
     position: "relative",
     zIndex: 99999,
  }
})

function MyComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <div className={classes.imageContainer}></div>
  )
}
```

And I am trying to convert it to this:

```
const imageContainer = {
     display: "flex",
     width: "65%",
     float: "left",
     marginRight: "2px",
     position: "relative",
     zIndex: 99999,
}
function MyComponent2() {
  

  return (
      <Box sx={imageContainer}></Box>
  )
}
```

I get the error "no overload matches this call". If I do it like inline with sx it works:

```
   <Box sx={{display: "flex",
     width: "65%",
     float: "left",
     marginRight: "2px",
     position: "relative",
     zIndex: 99999}} 
    >
        ...
    </Box>
```

Oddly enough, if I take away float and position I can pass it in as I planned:

```
const imageContainer = {
     display: "flex",
     width: "65%",
     //float: "left",
     marginRight: "2px",
     //position: "relative",
     zIndex: 99999,
}
function MyComponent2() {


  return (
      <Box sx={imageContainer}></Box>
  )
}
```

Or should I just continue to use makeStyles? But if I do that, how long do I have before they get rid of it? Because it says it's deprecated. Does that mean eventually it'll be removed?
Thanks

Comment: Not every property is supported by sx prop in MUI.
marginRight in sx defined as "mr".

Comment: Then how come I can pass those properties inline? As I said, I can go sx={{float: 'left'}} no problem, but I can't pass an object with {float: 'left'}. I find it curious that it allows it one way and not another.

Comment: I checked on mine its working fine. showing float property if i define it as an object and pass it...
try creating obj within the function

Comment: You're using typescript? Just to make sure I'm not making a stupid mistake, I just tried it with: const obj={float: 'left'} and then <Box sx={obj} and the compiler still complains that there's 'no overload that matches this call'. If I change it to display: flex or bgcolor: 'red' it goes away. That's really weird. I'm sure there's a good reason but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Can you tell me what's in your tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 3):

if you're using typescript you have to define it as

```js
    const imageContainer = {
     display: "flex",
     width: "65%",
     float: "left",
     marginRight: "2px",
     position: "relative",
     zIndex: 99999,
} as const;
```

[Reference](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#typescript-usage)